# Java String concatenation and System.out.println doesnt work

Tags: java, string

i have a file with 100 names i try to print on screen.

```
StringTokenizer sb = new StringTokenizer(fileContents, " ,\n\t");
  while (sb.hasMoreElements())
  {
     String name = sb.nextToken();
     System.out.print(name);
     System.out.print(" [ ");
     System.out.println();
  }
```

When i have `//System.out.print(" [ ");` commented out, it displays all 100 names correctly.

Uncommenting it will display 100 lines with `" [ "` only, the names aren't displayed at all.

Why this happens ? it's my first time `system.out.println` decides to ignore input.

Comment: Maybe you have some special characters in that file that appear as empty? Hence the "[" only lines?

Comment: Why not to just use `System.out.prinln(name+" [ ")`?

Comment: could be empty line or whitechar ?

Comment: @pepuch because it will create a new StringBuilder every time it is called?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with just a few names? Can you provide the `fileContents`? I cannot repro the issue.

Comment: Are you using the same fileContents in both the scenarios ?

Comment: Post for us example code that doesn't involve any external files.

Comment: Maybe try to add \r to the StringTokenizer list

Comment: This is working fine. With java version 6

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari Looking at code it will work fine. Issue might be with the fileContents. Do you have the same fileContents as the OP ?

Comment: it was \r character inside the file that caused the problem, thank you after adding it on string tokenizer list it worked for both situations.
Btw i tried to edit my post to show this but it takes forever to load.

Comment: @user2186597 Since I got it right, I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your file's encoding may include other characters that could cause an empty (or `[`) line to be printed.

Try adding carriage return `\r` special character to your list in StringTokenizer.

Comment: thank you all for help, i cant upvote yet since it says i need 15 reputation to upvote.

Comment: @user2186597 you can probably accept the question by clicking the empty v to the left of the answer.